# search and replace regex in gvim

Tags: regex, unix, vim

I am trying to **replace/delete** few columns in a pattern.

example of the pattern is as follows:

```
(. xx,asdf,gh,df.)
```

And i want to make it like:

```
(.asdf,gh,df.)
```

For search,i used `/(.\zs[^,]\ze[^,^,^.)]`
This is not helping the search.
This is also highlighting first column in every pattern. i.e ex (. 12, 23,34.) pattern also.

the answer to my search is highlighting x in the first pattern and empty space before 1 in second pattern.

i want my search to work for the first pattern only.
The first step of search for me is not working as expected.

could some one help me out here.
thanks a lot for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you give other examples of what you want as original strings and replacements? From this sample alone, we cannot tell

Comment: you want to search&highlight or replace ?

Comment: I want to search and replace...but the first step of search itself is not working.    the regex i am working with is as follows (. 12, 0012, 23, 00), (. 11, 00ff, 34, 10), ..... i want to remove in all these place the the first 2 digit field and the comma before the 4 digit field.  -@krishna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:%s#\v(\(\.)([^,]{-},)(.{-}\.\))#\1\3#g
```

this will do the replacement: `(. xx,asdf,gh,df.)` -> `(.asdf,gh,df.)`

if you just want to highlight it (in your case is  `_xx` "_ means space") you could try with look-behind:

```
/\((\.\)\@<=[^,]*
```

**EDIT** based on comment

assume we have a file :

```
(. xx,asdf,gh,df,foo.)
(. xx,asdf,gh,df.)
(. xx,gh,df.)
(. xx,df.)
(. xx.)
```

in vim:

```
:%s#\v(\(\.)([^,]*,)([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,\.]*\.\))#\1\3#g
```

we got:

```
(. xx,asdf,gh,df,foo.)
(.asdf,gh,df.)
(. xx,gh,df.)
(. xx,df.)
(. xx.)
```

Comment: Thanks @kent....but there is problem with this search...
i want the search to work on only ex: (. 12, 2344, 34, 00.) patterns only and not on ex(. 3323, 24,33.) patterns...

Comment: Thanks @kent....but there is problem with this search...
i want the search to work on only ex: (. 12, 2344, 34, 00.) patterns only and not on ex(. 3323, 24,33.) patterns...

Let me give an example. 
(.00, 0000, 00, 00.),(.1222, 55,99.),(12, ffff, 45, 56.),(23, 00ff, 45, 77.),(.0ff0,22, 00.)........

the pattern above is part of a very big array of patterns. few of them are 4 field patterns and few are 3 field patterns and i want the search string to work on 4 field patterns only.

Comment: @krishnachaitanya you should accept his answer by clicking the little arrow below the big arrows that point up and down, to the left of his answer.